# how to play youtube video at last when all element is load

Tags: html, dom

I Load YouTube video in my page and buy it play before other element load.
so page loading speed make slow...

```
<div class="wel_come_msg">
    <div class="video_box">
        <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/rDm7WstKG8s?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: see the `autoplay=1` in your link? guess what happens when you set it to 0.  http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/3TH3s/

Comment: Similar question like;


[Is there a way to load embedded YouTube videos faster on my website?][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268482/is-there-a-way-to-load-embedded-youtube-videos-faster-on-my-website/16014030#16014030

Comment: @Banana: He wants to play the video after the page is loaded. When `autoplay` is unset that doesn't happen

Comment: @Augustus Francis in this case i'm afraid using html alone is not enough. op will have to load the video manually using javascript after DOM is loaded

Comment: @Banana Yes, Also He didn't seemed against using jQuery.

Comment: @Augustus Francis true, but it would be the same as suggesting someone to burn down the whole house because he asked to get rid of a spider :)

Answer (score -2):

Change your iframe to

```
<iframe id="video" width="100%" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).load(function(){
  $("#video").attr("src","http://www.youtube.com/embed/rDm7WstKG8s?autoplay=1")
});
```

Answer (score -2):

This will hide the div that the player is in for 2 seconds while page loads.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">  
    $(window).load(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#contentPost").show('fadeIn', {}, 500)
        }, 2000);
    });
    </script>

    <style>
    .video_box { display:none;}
    </style>

    <div class="wel_come_msg">
        <div class="video_box">
            <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/rDm7WstKG8s?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: no, this will show the div 2 seconds after the entire window's content is fully loaded. you could skip the setTimeout and achieve the same result. still, op did not ask for a jQuery solution.

Comment: This is not jQuery for one it's Javascript. Secondly it is not possible with html alone.

Comment: man i wont even bother arguing with you. please learn what jquery is.

Comment: I included the setTimeout because the op did not specify which element is not being loaded before the player. He can play with the timing better by using the setTimout.

Comment: just to assist you avoid embarrassing situations in the future, i will leave this link here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp, and silently back away