# AWS CloudFront vs Youtube - what's the faster way to load videos on a webpage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3, youtube, web-performance

I need to include 42 tutorial videos on a single web page, between 30-90 seconds each. I'm currently uploading them to S3 in `mov` format and including them in the page with the `video` tag. 6 videos in, the page loads fast enough but the videos take ages to load.

It looks like I have 2 options to speed this up from the research I've done -

1 - Upload the videos to Youtube, load thumbnail images on the website and [replace them with the video when the user clicks on the thumbnail image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16014030/3906773).

2 - [Use Amazon CloudFront to deliver the videos to the user](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/using-amazon-cloudfront-for-video-streaming/).

Which of these is a faster way of delivering videos to the user? Youtube seems to be the cheaper option with the added advantage of allowing the user to stream videos on Youtube but AWS CloudFront seems like a service specially built for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest if you want less complexity and fast setup use You Tube. Even if AWS CF is build for this purpose you will have to create a infrastructure for hosting those videos, which in case of you tube you have to just embed the video using the embed code.

As per costing goes Youtube is less cheaper almost free. If you create Cloud Front for the distribution you have to pay for Storage of the Videos, Data Transfer Cost and many more. You will get a very good speed for youtube videos worldwide. Also you have to create a video player in your application for video streaming which is again more work.